# Suspect in past continuous (were suspecting )

Tags: stative-verbs

In my understanding 'suspect' is a stative verb, therefore is not used in continuous times. But I came across the following sentences: "I suggested to the team that what we were really suspecting was an intellectual disability." and "The accused was suspecting the fidelity of his wife Geetha.". Are these sentences correct and why?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Suspect can be used in continuous forms, just like "think".

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspect),
"suspect" can mean "to imagine ...", "to doubt ...", and all of them can be used in continuous forms.